# How do I exclude deleted bot messages on my on_message_delete event?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm new to python and decided to try doing bots in discord. I've been creating a bot that could log deleted messages in a specific channel but sometimes when a bot deletes a message, it gets spammy. I'd want to know if there's a way I could ignore a specific role. I've been trying stuff myself and I had no luck. I'd really appreciate suggestions as my brain can't think of any way how to.

Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    author = message.author
    content = message.content
    channel = client.get_channel(706552106219470849)
    if author == client.user:
        return
    await channel.send(f'{author}: {content}')
```

Comment: Most likely, yes, can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the ID of the person who deleted the roles.

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete():
    #########
    # setup #
    #########
    ignores = (1, 2, 3, 4) # those who have user IDs of 1, 2, 3, or 4 will be ignored

    if message.author.id not in ignores:
        ############
        # do stuff #
        ############
```

Comment: You can just insert your preexisting code up at the top and put your do stuff (`await channel.send()`) there